# LNK2019 error when calling template function

Tags: c++

I have the following template function, which builds a `std::unordered_set` object from a `std::list` object:

```
template<typename T>
std::unordered_set<T> *SetUtils::list_to_set(const std::list<T>& list) {
    std::unordered_set<T> *set = new std::unordered_set<T>();
    for (typename std::list<T>::const_iterator it = list.begin() ; it != list.end(); ++it) {
        set->insert(*it);
    }

    return set;
}
```

I tried running it on a list of strings, expecting to get a set of strings:

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> *point_set = SetUtils::list_to_set(*point_list);
```

Where `point_list` is defined earlier as:

```
std::list<std::string> *point_list = new std::list<std::string>();
```

When I try to compile it, I get the following error:

```
kuku.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static class std::unordered_set<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,struct std::hash<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,struct std::equal_to<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > * __cdecl SetUtils::list_to_set<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > >(class std::list<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> >,class std::allocator<class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > > > const &)" (??$list_to_set@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@SetUtils@@SAPEAV?$unordered_set@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@U?$hash@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@U?$equal_to@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@std@@AEBV?$list@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V?$allocator@V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@2@@2@@Z) referenced in function "public: class std::unordered_map<double,class std::unordered_map<double,double,struct std::hash<double>,struct std::equal_to<double>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<double const ,double> > >,struct std::hash<double>,struct std::equal_to<double>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<double const ,class std::unordered_map<double,double,struct std::hash<double>,struct std::equal_to<double>,class std::allocator<struct std::pair<double const ,double> > > > > > * __cdecl FrameAnalyzer::computeFrameAnalytics(double *,unsigned int *,class std::list<struct TextTransitionMetric,class std::allocator<struct TextTransitionMetric> > &)" (?computeFrameAnalytics@FrameAnalyzer@@QEAAPEAV?$unordered_map@NV?$unordered_map@NNU?$hash@N@std@@U?$equal_to@N@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBNN@std@@@2@@std@@U?$hash@N@2@U?$equal_to@N@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBNV?$unordered_map@NNU?$hash@N@std@@U?$equal_to@N@2@V?$allocator@U?$pair@$$CBNN@std@@@2@@std@@@std@@@2@@std@@PEANPEAIAEAV?$list@UTextTransitionMetric@@V?$allocator@UTextTransitionMetric@@@std@@@3@@Z)
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ thank you very very much!!! The thread you redirected me solved the issue in a minute :)

Comment: De nada! It's very common ...